# Finding limits for uniform ratio distribution

Tags: integration, uniform-distribution

Suppose that *X*∼ Uniform(a,b) and *Y*~ Uniform(c,d).

Let Z =Y/X, I'm finding PDF Pr(Z$\leq$z).

I took the region for integration as $ \frac{c}{a} \leq z \leq \frac{d}{a}$ ; $ \frac{d}{b} \leq z \leq \frac{c}{a}$ ; $ \frac{c}{b} \leq z \leq \frac{d}{b}$. For many situations this region of 
 integration seems wrong.

Why this region of integration is wrong?